# Pair of points with distance divisible by integer

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, integer-division

I came across an interview questions and despite the fact I've been trying to solve it on my own I think I need some help.

I've got an array of integer numbers (positive and negative) representing points in space, the distance between two points is defined as abs(A[i]-A[j]) and I need to check that that distance is divisible by a given integer M.

So this is the situation :

Array : [-3 -2 1 0 8 7 1]

M = 3

abs(A[1]-A[2]) = 3 (for example and it's divisible by the integer)

The complexity should be O(N+M) and the space O(M)

Now these are the questions

1)I know there is a way to take in consideration al the couples without using the obvious solution with two "for loops" because the complexity would be N^2 which is undesirable, but I can't figure out how to do it

2)Complexity O(N+M) means that I need to use two for loops but not one inside another?(I mean two separate for loops), what I am trying to understand here it's if the complexity given can guide me toward the best algorithm I should use.

3)When the specification says that the integer name is M and the complexity is O(N+M), does this mean that there is a relation with the integer M and the complexity or it's only a case that the name is the same?

4)How to do it ?

I hope I have been clear enough, if not please let me know I wil try to explain myself better.

Ok Let's see if I understood correctly this is what I am trying so far :

```
int testCollection[7];

testCollection[0] = -3;
testCollection[1] = -2;
testCollection[2] = 1;
testCollection[3] = 0;
testCollection[4] = 8;
testCollection[5] = 7;
testCollection[6] = 1;

int arrayCollection[7];

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    arrayCollection[i] = 1000;
}

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{

    arrayCollection[i] = testCollection[i]%3;

}
```

the arrayCollection now contains: [0, -2, 1, 0, 2, 1 ,1 ]

I did not understand what you mean for second time can you please be a little bit more specific? Imagine I am a child :)

cheers

p.s. I don't want to disturb you too much so if you prefer you can point me to some documentation I can read about the subject, googling I did not find much unfortunately.

Comment: Regarding 3) When the integer -is- M, the complexity should be O(N+M). I.e., when M is larger you get more time than when M is small.

Answer (score 5):

Two points have the same `mod M` if and only if they are an integer multiple of `M` apart. So make a integer array `A` of size `mod M`, and loop over the `N` integers, for each such integer `N[i]`, effecting `A[N[i] % M]++`.

At the end, if any entry is `>1`, then there is at least one pair of integers that are a multiple of `M` apart.

To actually extract a solution (i.e., get the values that are `k*M` apart rather than simply knowing there are some), you can initialize entires of `A` to `MAXINT`, and assign the value to `A` the first time a particular `mod M` is seen. The second time you have the pair of values that work.

Answer (score 4):

The key to solving this problem efficiently is realizing this one property:

"All points that are `m` (or a multiple of `m`) units away, will give the same modulo `m` result."

```py
mod_res = num % m
```

This also implies the reverse, i.e. "all points that give the same modulo `m` result, are exactly a multiple of `m` units away."

Here is a small drawing to illustrate this with the numbers from your question:

[image: Number line with modulo positions]

Once we understand the relation between this modulo property and the relative distance between points, it becomes easy to code this out.

We just need to calculate the modulo_result of every number, and then group together numbers that have the same modulo_result.

```py
def solution(array: List[int], m: int) -> int:
    # Maintain a hashmap of modulo_results and a list of numbers that resolve to that result
    modulo_results = defaultdict(list)
    for num in array:
        # Insert every number into the corresponding module_result list
        res = num % m
        modulo_results[res].append(num)
    
    # Now simply loop through every modulo_result list and find the longest one
    max_subset_size = 0
    max_subset = []
    for res, nums in modulo_results.items():
        if len(nums) > max_subset_size:
            max_subset_size = len(nums)
            max_subset = nums

    print(f"Max subset: {max_subset}")
    return max_subset_size

# print(solution([-3, -2, 1, 0, 8, 7, 1], m=3))
# Max subset: [-2, 1, 7, 1]
# 4
```

This solution takes `O(n)` time and `O(n)` extra space.

Comment: May I ask how do you come up with the intuition? This problem becomes so trivial with the modulo property, but I have a hard time figure this out intuitively.

Comment: I think its just experience with similar problems. Over time you develop the intuition of knowing where to apply what logic.

Answer (score 1):

Implemented in kotlin kindly check below:

```kotlin
fun largestSubSetDivisible(array: Array<Int>, m: Int):Int {
    val result = Array(1) { 1 }
    largestSubSetDivisible(array, m = m, result = result)
    return result[0]
}

fun largestSubSetDivisible(
    array: Array<Int>,
    arr: IntArray = IntArray(array.size) { 0 },
    i: Int = 0,
    m: Int,
    result: Array<Int> = Array(1) { 1 }
) {
    fun checkDivisionPair(array: List<Int>, m: Int): Boolean {
        for (j in 0 until array.size - 1) {
            if ((array[j] - array[j + 1]) % m != 0)
                return false
        }
        return true
    }
    if (i == array.size) {
        val count = arr.count { it == 1 }
        if (result[0] < count) {
            val ar = array.filterIndexed { index, _ -> arr[index] == 1 }
            if (checkDivisionPair(ar, m))
                result[0] = count
        }
        return
    }
    arr[i] = 0
    largestSubSetDivisible(array, arr, i + 1, m, result)
    arr[i] = 1
    largestSubSetDivisible(array, arr, i + 1, m, result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code runs in O(M+N) and O(M) extra space.

```
modulus = (num,n)=>{
    if(num<0){
        do{
            num += n;
        }while(num<0);
    }
    return num%n;
}
var arr=[-5,-2,4,7,10,0,8],m=3,mod=[];
for(var index=0;index<m;index++){
    mod[index]=0;
}
for(index=0;index<arr.length;index++){
    mod[modulus(arr[index],m)]++;
}
mod.sort(function(a,b){
    return a-b;
});
if(mod[m-1] > 1){
    console.log(mod[m-1]);
}
```

I came across this question recently in an interview. So, I assumed your question was a part of the same question I was asked.

Answer (score 0):

C++ based Solution

```
int sol(std::vector<int> vec, int M)
{
    std::vector<int> mod(M);
    for (int p = 0; p < M; ++p) {
        mod[p] = 0;
    }
    for(int i : vec)
    {
        mod[(std::abs(vec[i]) % M)] = mod[(std::abs(vec[i]) % M)] + 1;
    }
    std::sort(mod.begin(), mod.end());
    return mod[M - 1];
}
int main( void )
{
    std::cout << sol({ -3, -2, 1, 0, 8, 7, 1 }, 3) << std::endl; // 4
    std::cout << sol({7, 1, 11, 8, 4, 10}, 8) << std::endl; // 2
    return 0;
}
```